# Download multiple files from a .zip file via FTP

Tags: r, dataframe

Good morning everyone

I need to download a .zip file via FTP.

The .zip file contains inside .pdf files, .csv files and other .zip files. I would like to understand how to download each individual file

```
library(RCurl)
library(stringr) 



url = "ftp://ftp.xxxxxxxxx.it"

zip_file = getURL(url, userpwd=userpwd, ftp.use.epsv = FALSE, dirlistonly = TRUE)
filenames <- strsplit(filenames, "\r\n")
filenames = unlist(filenames)

I am trying this but I only get the list of contained files

 [1] "Nuovo_tracciato_v3.csv"               "Nuovo_tracciato_v3.zip"                 "Nuovo_tracciato_v4_html.csv"         
 [4] "Nuovo_tracciato_v4_html.zip"     "Nuovo_tracciato_v5.csv"               "Nuovo_tracciato_v5.zip"              
 [7] "OLD"                                                 "Specifiche_tracciati.xls"                  "Tracciati_web_IC_INTRACOM_ITALIA.pdf"
[10] "Tracciato_SKU_CODICEFORNITORE.csv"
```

How can I do? Thanks in advance to anyone who can help me solve this problem

Comment: @KJ  I changed the code. Following your instructions, I find the .zip file in the zip_file variable? But with str () it says it's just a character vector

Comment: Hi @rw. Logically your suggestion is right but I was missing a step. I had to change the url and insert username and password at the beginning and then change the last of the url according to the file of my interest